# is there a way to keep only the year of the date in r?

Tags: r, date

How do I keep only the year for my date in r? the dates are coded in a csv file in the format "30SEP2018" or "12APR1999" for example. I have thousands of rows of data. what is the best way for me to only keep the last four digits?

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can do

```
df$Year <- format(as.Date(df$Date, "%d%b%Y"), "%Y")
df
#       Date Year
#1 30SEP2018 2018
#2 12APR1999 1999
```

Read `?strptime` to get all possible date-time formats.

Using `lubridate`, you don't have to remember the formats.

```
library(lubridate)
df$year <- year(dmy(df$date))
```

---

Usually, it is recommended to handle date and time using standard functions for them as above and not with string manipulation, here is one way that gets the last 4 numbers from each string.

```
df$year <- sub(".*(\\d{4}$)", "\\1", x)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("30SEP2018", "12APR1999"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `substr` here, as your column is already text:

```
df$year <- substr(df$date, 6, 9)
```

We could also use `sub`:

```
df$year <- sub("^.*(\\d{4})$", "\\1", df$date)
```